# Form submit button with two different IDs

Tags: html

I need to make a submit button work with two different IDs. Below is the HTML code:

```
Button: <button class="some class" type="submit" id="gform_submit_button add_to_quote">Submit</button>
```

Since it's not possible to assign two different IDs to a button, what's the best way to deal with it?

Comment: Without even seen your site, it sounds like pretty bad design providing two buttons doing the exact same job... But back to your problem: Easiest way is to do it with JavaScript. Create an `onclick` on your buttons that calls a JavaScript function.

Comment: People didn't understand my question or I think I didn't explain it properly. What if i say i've to make a submit button work with two different ID's? Like this <button type="button" id="gform_submit_button add_to_quote">Submit</button>. I know it's not going to work but what's the best way to make it work?

Comment: I think you're stuck in defining your problem. What do you ACTUALLY want to achieve. What should happen when hitting that button? And why do you want to have two IDs on one element? That's kind of not how IDs work since they are supposed to be unique...

Comment: There are two IDs.
1. gform_submit_button : Checks for validation errors.
2. add_to_quote : Adds the submitted form entries to quote.

So when button is hit, it should validate the form & then submit it.

Comment: Allright, that doesn't sound that hard... How do you validate, and how do you submit? You're not using any JavaScript at all?

Comment: I need to use "gform_submit_button" identifier to validate the form when the form is submitted. But submit button already has an ID so not sure how to make it work. https://www.gravityhelp.com/documentation/article/gform_submit_button/

Comment: Sorry if I'm wrong, but the first line I read in the documentation is this: `"This filter is executed when the form is displayed and can be used to completely change the form button tag (i.e. <input type="submit">)."` isn't that pretty much the answer to your question? If it's already validated, why bother validating it again?

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to create a button (it doesn't need an id) and attach a JavaScript event handler to submit the form programatically when clicked.

For example:

```
<form name="myForm" action="...">
    <!-- Form elements go here -->
    <button id="button1">Submit Button 1</button>
    <button id="button2">Submit Button 2</button>
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var button1 = document.getElementById('button1'),
        button2 = document.getElementById('button2');

    function submitForm() {
        document.myForm.submit();
    }

    button1.addEventListener('click', submitForm);
    button2.addEventListener('click', submitForm);
    
</script>
```

Comment: I just need a submit button to work with two different IDs, you know how it can be done? There is only one form.

Comment: So, just to make sure I understand, you only need to submit one of the two forms, but would like a single button to submit either one or the other depending on some logic?

Comment: Ah, there's only one form, but two buttons that should submit the same form, correct? I'll update my answer.

Comment: There's 1 form & 1 submit button. Two different button IDs. "gform_submit_button" & " add_to_quote". How to make the button work?

Comment: DOM Elements can't have more than one id. If you need to programatically refer to elements and absolutely need different identifiers to do so, you could add a data attribute or class name instead.